# Probability of Outcomes Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, probability, probability-theory

I have a probability problem, which I need to simulate in a reasonable amount of time.  In simplified form, I have 30 unfair coins each with a different known probability.  I then want to ask things like "what is the probability that exactly 12 will be heads?", or "what is the probability that AT LEAST 5 will be tails?".

I know basic probability theory, so I know I can enumerate all (30 choose x) possibilities, but that's not particularly scalable.  The worst case (30 choose 15) has over 150 million combinations.  Is there a better way to approach this problem from a computational standpoint?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks! :-)

Comment: Are you looking for a closed-form expression?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a dynamic programming approach.

For example, to calculate the probability of 12 heads out of 30 coins, let P(n, k) be the probability that there's k heads from the first n coins.

Then P(n, k) = p_n * P(n - 1, k - 1) + (1 - p_n) * P(n - 1, k)

(here p_i is the probability the i'th coin is heads).

You can now use this relation in a dynamic programming algorithm. Have a vector of 13 probabilities (that represent P(n - 1, i) for i in 0..12). Build a new vector of 13 for P(n, i) using the above recurrence relation. Repeat until n = 30. Of course, you start with the vector (1, 0, 0, 0, ...) for n=0 (since with no coins, you're sure to get no heads).

The worst case using this algorithm is O(n^2) rather than exponential.

Comment: Doesn't the other algorithm have O(n!) complexity rather than exponential?

Comment: Nope, I'm pretty sure it's O(n^2) like Paul said, because you leverage the work of each previous iteration using the dynamic programming method.

Comment: @mR_fr0g The worst case for the brute-force solution is choose(n, n / 2). This is less than 2^n and greater than 2^(n / 2)... so the algorithm is exponential.

Comment: It makes sense when I draw out a graph/table and try to figure it out, but I have no idea how you would actually come up with that on the fly (as in an interview question).

Answer (score 15):

This is actually an interesting problem. I was inspired to write a blog post about it covering in detail fair vs unfair coin tosses all the way to the OP's situation of having a different probability for each coin. You need a technique called dynamic programming to solve this problem in polynomial time.

**General Problem:** Given *C*, a series of *n* coins *p*<sub>*1*</sub> to *p*<sub>*n*</sub> where *p*<sub>*i*</sub> represents the probability of the *i*-th coin coming up heads, what is the probability of *k* heads coming up from tossing all the coins?

This means solving the following recurrence relation:

*P*(*n*,*k*,*C*,*i*) = *p*<sub>*i*</sub> x *P*(*n*-1,*k*-1,*C*,*i*+1) + (1-*p*<sub>*i*</sub>) x *P*(*n*,*k*,*C*,*i*+1)

A Java code snippet that does this is:

```
private static void runDynamic() {
  long start = System.nanoTime();
  double[] probs = dynamic(0.2, 0.3, 0.4);
  long end = System.nanoTime();
  int total = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < probs.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%d : %,.4f%n", i, probs[i]);
  }
  System.out.printf("%nDynamic ran for %d coinsin %,.3f ms%n%n",
      coins.length, (end - start) / 1000000d);
}

private static double[] dynamic(double... coins) {
  double[][] table = new double[coins.length + 2][];
  for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    table[i] = new double[coins.length + 1];
  }
  table[1][coins.length] = 1.0d; // everything else is 0.0
  for (int i = 0; i <= coins.length; i++) {
    for (int j = coins.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      table[i + 1][j] = coins[j] * table[i][j + 1] +
          (1 - coins[j]) * table[i + 1][j + 1];
    }
  }
  double[] ret = new double[coins.length + 1];
  for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
    ret[i] = table[i + 1][0];
  }
  return ret;
}
```

What this is doing is constructing a table that shows the probability that a sequence of coins from *p*<sub>i</sub> to *p*<sub>n</sub> contain *k* heads.

For a deeper introduction to binomial probability and a discussion on how to apply dynamic programming take a look at [Coin Tosses, Binomials and Dynamic Programming](http://www.cforcoding.com/2010/08/coin-tosses-binomials-and-dynamic.html).

Comment: Thanks for this answer and your blog post, I now believe to understand dynamic programming :)

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
    procedure PROB(n,k,p)
/*
    input: n - number of coins flipped
           k - number of heads
           p - list of probabilities  for n-coins where p[i] is probability coin i will be heads
    output: probability k-heads in n-flips
    assumptions: 1 <= i <= n, i in [0,1], 0 <= k <= n, additions and multiplications of [0,1] numbers O(1)
*/

A = ()() //matrix
A[0][0] = 1 // probability no heads given no coins flipped = 100%

for i = 0  to  k                                                              //O(k)
    if  i != 0  then  A[i][i] = A[i-1][i-1] * p[i]
    for j = i + 1  to  n - k + i                                              //O( n - k + 1 - (i + 1)) = O(n - k) = O(n)
        if i != 0 then  A[i][j] = p[j] * A[i-1][j-1] + (1-p[j]) * A[i][j-1]
        otherwise       A[i][j] = (1 - p[j]) * A[i][j-1]
return A[k][n] //probability k-heads given n-flips
```

Worst case = O(kn)